# AWS::CloudFormation::Init yum update fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Got a little problem, so part of my json file I want to run a command to update all the packages the following command is:

```
        "commands" : {
          "update_yum_packages" : {
            "command" : "sudo yum update -y"
          }
        },
```

Now if I remove this from my json file the stack will create with no issues, however when I add the command I get an error from **AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition**. I have set the timeout to **1200** is there something clearly wrong here ?

I can run the command fine once I ssh onto the new instance.

Comment: Try running it without `sudo`. If that fails, paste the relevant log entries from `/var/log/cloud-init*`.

Comment: @tedder42, you can answer directly, I also think that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the log files in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log.

You will see that it complains about running a sudo command without a tty:

```
cloud-init-output.log:sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

The user data is run as root, you don't need to use "sudo". And using sudo will fail, and make the cloud-init process fail.

So just use:

```
    "commands" : {
      "update_yum_packages" : {
        "command" : "yum update -y"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This yaml should do the same thing without you having to directly call sudo

```
#cloud-config
---
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
package_reboot_if_required: true
```